# Testing with Community User, getNetworkId return null

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app

1.

```
 public class UnitTestUtils{
    public Community_Settings__c genCommunityCustomSettings() {
        Community_Settings__c settings = new Community_Settings__c(
            Image_CDN__c = 'http://cdn.com',
            Auto_Add_Chatter_Group_Names__c = genPublicChatterGroup()
        );
        settings.Name = 'Settings';
        insert settings;
        return settings;
    }
 }

 private static void setupData() {

        customSettings  = new customSettings__c(
            CommunityName__c = 'CName',
            grpPermissionSet__c = 'permissionSet',
            // some more  
            oginPageUrl__c = 'apex/dummyPage',                      
            DevPermissionSet__c = 'permissionSet'
        );
        customSettings.Name = 'CSettings'; 
        insert customSettings;

        utils = new UnitTestUtils();
        utils.genCommunityCustomSettings();

    } 

        public Account genPersonAccount() {
            Account newPersonAccount = new Account();
            newPersonAccount.FirstName = 'Tom';
            newPersonAccount.LastName = 'Cat';
            newPersonAccount.PersonEmail = 'TomCat+' + genRandomNumber() + '@example.com';
            newPersonAccount.RecordTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
            newPersonAccount.BillingCountry = 'US';
            insert newPersonAccount;
            return [SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, PersonEmail, RecordTypeId, PersonContactId from Account where id = :newPersonAccount.id];
        }


    public User genPersonAccountUser(Account a) {
        User testUser = new User();
        testUser.Username = a.PersonEmail;
        testUser.Lastname = a.Lastname;
        testUser.Firstname = a.Firstname;
        testUser.Alias = ('BR' + genRandomNumber()).left(8);
        testUser.ContactId = a.PersonContactId;
        testUser.email = a.PersonEmail;
        testUser.CommunityNickname = String.valueOf(genRandomNumber());
        testUser.ProfileId = [select id from profile where Name = 'Some_profile'].Id; 
        insert testUser;
        return testUser;
    }

    static void generateUser()
            {

                accountList=new List<Account>();
                userList=new List<user>();

                for(Integer i=0;i<10;i++)
                    accountList.add(genPersonAccount());


            for(Integer i=0;i<10;i++)
                userList.add(genPersonAccountUser(accountList[i]));

        }


    @isTest 
    public static void TestEmptySearchQuery() {    

        User thisUser = [ select Id from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
            System.runAs ( thisUser ) {     // running as thisUser to Avoid Error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION
            setupData();   
            generateUser(); // List of user assigned with some profile, as required for project.  

            list<PermissionSetAssignment> PSA = new  list<PermissionSetAssignment> ();
            PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id, name FROM PermissionSet where name='Some_Access'];
            system.debug('PermissionSet ' + ps);           
            for(user u:userList)
                PSA.add(new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = u.id, PermissionSetId = ps.Id));      // all the user assgined with 'some_access' based on requirement of project
            insert PSA;
        }

        Test.startTest(); 
        User usr = [select Id from User where Id = :userList[0].id];

        System.runAs(usr) {
            system.debug('Network ommunityId ****' + Network.getNetworkId());  //display null 
            SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
            Id Nid=obj.fetchNetworkId(); // return null;   
            system.debug('network id ' + Nid);  // null
        } 
        Test.stopTest();        
    } 

    class SomeClass {
    //some code
        public id fetchNetworkId() {
            system.debug('network id ' + Network.getNetworkId()); // network id is  
     null;
            return Network.getNetworkId(); // return null
        }
        // some code
    }
```

while executing visual force page, controller returns proper network id, 
when try to write a test class for this 'SomeClass' controller, community network id always return null.

2.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public static void TestEmptySearchQuery() {    
    Test.startTest(); 
     User u=[select Id,name from user where name ='SomeName']; // fetching user from org, same user, i log in as normal visual force page and executed, its working fine.
        System.runAs ( u ) {           
        system.debug('Network ommunityId ****' + Network.getNetworkId());  //display null 
        SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
        Id Nid=obj.fetchNetworkId(); // return null;   
        system.debug('network id ' + Nid);  // null
    } 
    Test.stopTest();        
}
```

second case i tried using org user , still i am facing same problem. without network id, My rest of the code will not run. i tried with with or without  test.startTest and stoptest all.
can anyone help me? what i am missing or doing anything wrong ?

Comment: first create a community user in test class and then check the network id in context of community user

Comment: @RatanPaul thanks for the response. i have add little more code to understand for you .

Comment: If i keep seeAllData=true , also it return null for network id.

Comment: @RatanPaul , Both case 1 and Case 2 network id is null, if you on my code for SeeAlllData, i need not be add any user and community assignment all . still it is fail to return network id .

Comment: is the name ='SomeName' user an community user?

Comment: @RatanPaul Yes Ratan . already existing user in that community. Same user i used log in and  executed through visual force page,  its returning proper network id.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes,  already existing user in that community.